# JSON to HTML (Codeigniter)

Tags: html, ajax, json, codeigniter

```
public function getCrew(){
    $search = $this->input->post('name');
    if($this->input->post('ajax') && (!empty($search))){
         $result = $this->model->getNames($search);
         foreach($result as $r){
            echo json_encode($r);
         }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#getMem').keyup(function(e){

    var name = {
        ajax: 1,
        name: $('#getMem').val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'work/getCrew',
        type: 'POST',
        data: name,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $('#freshMem').html(data.first_name);
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error.');
        }
    });
});

 });
```

This works fine if the result from database returns only one row, if more than one generates error, can anyone please tell me how to solve this

Comment: `Object {first_name: "Aman", last_name: "Shahi"}`, when the result is single row, after that it shows the ajax `alert('error')`

Comment: check my answer out. It would help if you can show what the JSON object looks like with multiple results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Output class to tell the browser that JSON is being returned. The problem is that you are `json_encode`ing multiple objects in your foreach loop. Just `json_encode` the array returned from your model

```
    public function getCrew(){

        $search = $this->input->post('name');
        if($this->input->post('ajax') && (!empty($search))){
             $result = $this->model->getNames($search);

             $this->output
                         ->set_content_type('application/json')
                         ->set_output(json_encode(array("response" => $result)));
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#getMem').keyup(function(e){
        var name = {
            ajax: 1,
            name: $('#getMem').val()
        }

            $.ajax({
                url: 'work/getCrew',
                type: 'POST',
                data: name,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data)
                {
                    var __html = '';

                    $.each(data.response, function (a, b) 
                    {

                        __html += '<p>'+b.first_name+'</p>';

                    });

                    $('#freshMem').html(__html);
                },
                error: function()
                {
                    alert('Error.');
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: this is for an autocomplete. same `first_name` is repeating on every `keyup`, when `.append` is used. i tried  with `.html` and `.text` but then only one name shows up. there is no error.

Comment: show me what your json data looks like with multiple results. Also why don't you use the jquery autocomplete widget

Comment: `Object {first_name: "Aman", last_name: "Shahi"}`, many objects like these. i'm learning ajax and json so jQuery alone is enough for me.

Comment: with `.append` multiple results show up but previous ones don't disappear.

Comment: okay so the only problem is that the other ones get appended below the previous ones. check my edit. it should work.

Comment: @NestedWeb check it out. This will replace all of the HTML in `#freshMem` when you make a new ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'work/getCrew',
        type: 'POST',
        data: name,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
             json_data = $.parseJSON(data);
                         $.each(json_data, function(i,item){
                           $('#freshMem').append(item.first_name);
            });
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error.');
        }
    });
```

You have to iterate over returned array.

Also you need to change your controller code:

```
public function getCrew(){
    $search = $this->input->post('name');
    if($this->input->post('ajax') && (!empty($search))){
         $result = $this->model->getNames($search);
         // assuming that $result is array...
         $json = json_encode($result);
         echo $json;
         /*foreach($result as $r){
            echo json_encode($r);
         }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show me the returned data from server via ajax request?